# how to install spark and configure spark standalone cluster in ubuntu 22.04 and connect it from RStudio installed on windows machine

Tags: r, apache-spark, sparkr

I have installed spark on Ubuntu (remote server) but I am unable to connect it from rstudio that is installed on my local machine(windows os).

Error in start_shell(master = master, spark_home = spark_home, spark_version = version,  :
SPARK_HOME directory '/opt/spark/' not found

> sc <- spark_connect(master = "spark://192.168.21.107:4040",

- ```
                  spark_home = "/opt/spark/",
  ```
- ```
                  version="3.1.2")
  ```

Error in start_shell(master = master, spark_home = spark_home, spark_version = version,  :
SPARK_HOME directory '/opt/spark/' not found

> sc <- spark_connect(master = "spark://192.168.21.107:7077",

- ```
                  spark_home = "/opt/spark/",
  ```
- ```
                  version="3.1.2")
  ```

Error in start_shell(master = master, spark_home = spark_home, spark_version = version,  :
SPARK_HOME directory '/opt/spark/' not found`

I want to connect the  spark from rstudio installed on Windowss machine